# How can I give access to special task owners in MS Project?

Tags: ms-project

I have about 100 tasks in an academic project and 5 students.

I created the *msp* file.

Now I want to give access to each of my students to their own tasks. No one should see the other tasks or change permission for editing `%Complete&Status&Comments`. Just these 3 field should be editable for allowed users.

The authentication should be taken from Active Directory login.

For example, Mr. Moris just can edit `%Complete&Status&Comments` fields for the task IDs 20, 77, and 90.

How can I do this? Do I need to develop a program in VBA, MPXJ, PHP, etc.?

Comment: This question belongs on [superuser](https://superuser.com) or [ProjectManagement](https://pm.stackexchange.com) as it does not relate to programming.

Comment: The correct way to do this is to set up your schedule as a master project with subprojects for each of your students. Each student would only have access to their own file, but you would see all of the tasks in the master project.